# Test if JavaScript string contains all of multiple values, in any order, and case-insensitive

Tags: javascript

I want to perform what should be a simple search on a string to see if it contains *all* of several search terms, in a case insensitive manner.

For example, "The quick brown fox" contains the words "fox" and "quick", so I want a function which can take those two words and show that the phrase contains them both, regardless of their order.

So I guess what I'm asking for is a string-based "AND" search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the `array.every()` method to check that every search term is included in a string.

I'm specifying the search terms as a single string, which will be split by spaces:

```
var haystackString = "The quick brown fox";
var needleString   = "fox quick";

var searchTerms = needleString.split(" ");

return searchTerms.every(function stringContains(element, index, array) {
    return haystackString.toUpperCase().includes(element.toUpperCase());
});
```

The above will return `true`.

Be aware that `toUpperCase()` might not work with all languages.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array of terms to a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Then use  use [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to find all matches in string. If the number of matches is identical to the number of terms, it contains all of them:

```js
var str = 'The quick brown fox';

function containsAll(str, terms) {
  var regexp = new RegExp(`\\b(${terms.join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');
  var matches = str.match(regexp);
  
  return matches !== null && matches.length === terms.length;
}

console.log(containsAll(str, ['fox', 'quick']));

console.log(containsAll(str, ['cat', 'quick']));
```